# Vue Typescript Component Jest Testing doesn't render values in html

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-cli

I'm attempting to focus on TDD with Typescript and so I built a new Vue project with the vue-cli (I selected to use Vue3, Typescript, and Jest). However when I ran the unit test out of the box it failed. After some investigation I found that the `mount` command from `@vue/test-utils` doesn't render any of the prop values:

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  props: {
    msg: String,
  }
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  msg!: string;
  test: string = "It's a test";
}
</script>
```

example.specs.ts

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";

describe("HelloWorld.vue", () => {
  it("renders props.msg when passed", async () => {
    const msg = "new message";
    const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, {
      props: { msg }
    });
    
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain(msg);
  });
});
```

When I print `wrapper.html()` I get the following:

```
<div class="hello" msg="new message"><h1></h1></div>
```

It doesn't seem to be rendering `msg` or `test` at all into the html. It has it listed as a prop, but that's about it.

I think one of the causes might be that I'm using a Typescript component instead of a traditional which might throw it off, but I'm not sure.

Any advice/tips?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was tracked to vue-jest. Just made a fix. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/pull/299

Answer (score 0):

1. Your HelloWorld component is not detected as a component, this is how you need to define it:

   ```
   @Component
   export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
     @Prop() msg!: string;
   ```

@Component tells the compiler its a component.

@Prop() tells the compiler the msg property is a prop.

2. Use `propsData` as mount options or use setProps [documentation link](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops):

   ```
   const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, {
     propsData: {
       msg, // or msg: msg, 
     },
   });
   ```

Result:

```
  console.log tests/unit/example.spec.ts:13
    <div class="hello">
      <h1>
        new message
      </h1>
      It's a test
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still haven't been able to get it to work though, but that's because I'm currently using Vue 3 so I've been jumping down that rabbit hole for the last little bit.

If all else fails, I'll be sure to just switch back and work with Vue 2.

Answer (score 0):

So this didn't exactly fix the problem, but it's an alternative method that I'm going to try: Instead of using class based components I went more for the functional based with the typescript implementation.

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      test: "It's a test" as string
    }
  }
});
</script>
```